# Android bitmap exposure

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-activity

I am including a photo editor in my app and so far I have solved the brightness and contrast option . But i don t know hot to set the color matrix for exposure and what are the values .

Brightness : values between -255 and 255

Color matrix

```
  ColorMatrix brightnessCM= new ColorMatrix(new float[]
               {
                1, 0,    0,    0,brightness,
                0,    1, 0,    0,brightness,
                0,    0,    1, 0,brightness,
                0,    0,    0,    1,0
        });
```

Contrast : values between 0 and 1

color matrix:

```
    ColorMatrix contrastCM = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0,    0,    0,0,
                    0,    contrast, 0,    0,0,
                    0,    0,    contrast, 0,0,
                    0,    0,    0,    1,0
            });
```

This 2 work but I don t know what is the color matrix for exposure . 
I found in a topic that it was equal with contrast but it s not true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it 
Value can be between -1 and 1

```
    float pow = (float) Math.pow(2,value);
    ColorMatrix exposureMatrix= new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    pow, 0,    0, 0,  0,
                    0,    pow, 0, 0,  0,
                    0,    0,    pow,0,0,
                    0,    0,    0,    1,0
            });
```

And here is for brightness /contrast

```
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
            {
                    contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                    0, 0, 0, 1, 0
            });
```

Comment: do you have other matrix values..like for shadow, highlights, saturatio, sharpness, temperature etc.. ?

Comment: yes for brightness/contrast   , but I did not used the other ones , I think they may be a combination of contrast and brightness ?

Comment: tried using the combination of those but no luck. It's hard to use on other effects especially for shadow and highlights